# Not able to read data from small JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am looking for 2 hours now

> how to read my Json Data within my JavaScript File, save it into a var
>   and print it out.

I just can't make it work.. Every solution I encountered didn't worked for me(because I'm a JS noob) 
Please help me out:

My Json File:

```
var Quotes = {
    "allQuotes": [{
        "person": "- Martin Luther King Jr.",
        "quote": "In the End, we will remember not the words of our enemies, but the silence of our friends."

    }, {
        "person": " Uknown",
        "quote": "I am big! It is the pictures that got small."

    }, {
        "person": "- Apocalypse Now",
        "quote": " love the smell of napalm in the morning."

    }, {
        "person": " - Gone With the Wind",
        "quote": "Frankly, my dear, I do not give a damn."

    }, {
        "person": "- - Knute Rockne All American",
        "quote": " Tell em to go out there with all they got and win just one for the Gipper."

    }, {
        "person": "- Walt Disney",
        "quote": " It is kind of fun to do the impossible."

    }]
}
```

I'm working with CodePen I forgot to tell: http://codepen.io/pat_the_hat_1992/pen/qqWmYL

//You can see my mess up there and edit

Comment: That's not JSON, the `var Quotes =` bit is illegal in JSON. It's Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is not valid JSON. JSON is simply just a data format. You're mixing JavaScript and JSON. You cannot assign (or create) variables in a JSON file.

```
{
"allQuotes": [{
    "person": "- Martin Luther King Jr.",
    "quote": "In the End, we will remember not the words of our enemies, but the silence of our friends."

}, {
    "person": " Uknown",
    "quote": "I am big! It is the pictures that got small."

}, {
    "person": "- Apocalypse Now",
    "quote": " love the smell of napalm in the morning."

}, {
    "person": " - Gone With the Wind",
    "quote": "Frankly, my dear, I do not give a damn."

}, {
    "person": "- - Knute Rockne All American",
    "quote": " Tell em to go out there with all they got and win just one for the Gipper."

}, {
    "person": "- Walt Disney",
    "quote": " It is kind of fun to do the impossible."

}]
}
```

without the `var Quotes =` will make your JSON file valid.

A JSON file can be downloaded in Javascript using the `XMLHttpRequest` object, or `$.ajax` if you use jQuery.

**Vanilla Javascript Example**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/myJsonFile.json');
xhr.onload = function() {
    var quotes = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(quotes);
};
xhr.send();
```

or... if you use jQuery:

**jQuery Example**

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/myJsonFile.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }
  });
```

Note, using `$.ajax` or `XMLHttpRequest` requires you to be hosting your file on a web server. This will **not** work if the page is located on your local filesystem.

**Further Reading**

More informationon `XMLHttpRequest` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

More info with `JSON` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

More info with Jquery's `$.ajax`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Ok, thanks so far.
For my project the data set needs to be within my JS file, so I just need to re-declare my data set in my Js to access and output elements?

Also I'm not sure if I do need an array or if it's better without the array?

Comment: If you don't need to pull JSON from a separate file, and have complete control over the JSON content, you can hard-code JSON inside your javascript. In that case, you can copy the contents of your JSON file (including the `var Quotes =`) directly inside your javascript and Quotes should be available immediately. No need to `JSON.parse(Quotes)` or anything.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that you can see my project here:http://codepen.io/pat_the_hat_1992/pen/qqWmYL

Comment: Thank you, also for you hints.. I need to get way more knowledge about this totally embarrassing :D

I try to make it work in my project now

Comment: No problem! We all have gone through this path at one point in time. It's how we learn!

Comment: But if I try to output your "random2" variable it returns me [object Object] instead of the quote

Comment: All objects in javascript contains a `toString()` function, which is commonly invoked when a function expects a string. An `Object.toString()` will return `[object Object]`. For example if you add two strings together, `"myString" + myObject`. Then `myObject` will turn into a string `[object Object]`.

Comment: `random2` variable is an object that contains 2 properties: `person` and `quote`. So if you want to access `quote`, you need to write `random2.quote`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, this is how i am doing

```
var obj = JSON.parse(Quotes);
for (var i = 0; i < obj.allQuotes.length; i++) {
var counter = obj.allQuotes[i];
alert(counter.person+" says "+ counter.quote);
}
```

Comment: I tryed, but unfortunately it's not working for me.
Maybe my data set is wrong?

Comment: It should work assuming js variable **Quotes** contains the correct json string

Comment: If I hit run nothing happens

Comment: please open browser console, or change console.log to alert and run again

Comment: If this really helped you, please mark this answer the best. Thanks anyways !!

Comment: I am not sure why this code is not running in my codepen project

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the method shown on the W3C website? It uses '+' to make the JSON text:

```
    var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
    '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
    '{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
    '{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';
```

then to turn the JSON into a Javascript Object, so Javascript can read it:

```
    var object = JSON.parse(text);
```

to use the object in your code you would use something like this:

```
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML =
    obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
```

in this example it would print "John Doe" because *obj.employees[0].firstName* is equal to "John" and *obj.employees[0].lastName* is equal to "Doe"

If you wanted to use JQuery instead to print out the data:

```
    $("id").append(obj.employees[0].firstName + " " + obj.employees[0].lastName);
```

or

```
    $("id").text(obj.employees[0].firstName + " " + obj.employees[0].lastName);
```

Sample code on how to implement this onto a real webpage (this one prints out "Anna Smith" into the H1 Element):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 id="demo"></h1>
        <script>
            var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
            '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
            '{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
            '{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';

            var obj = JSON.parse(text);

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Comment: Isn't it zero based index?

Yes i kinda tryed that in my first approach but I just didn't run.
I tryed it with the example you provided again, but it's not working.. 

obj.employees[1].firstName  <-- is obj. = text OR Object?

Thanks so far!

Comment: Oh yeah your right it is zero based sorry about that and I tried the code and it works give me a second or two and I will post the exact code